# MVC displaying viewdata containing array

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

From the view this is the call to the controller,

```
 $('#Submit').click(function () {

            var params = { Id: $('#ID').val() };

            $('#Summary').html("Loading...");

            $.ajax({
                url: '<%= Url.Action("Summary", "Home") %>',
                data: params,
                success: function (html) {
                    $('#Summary').html(html);
                },
                cache: false
            });

        });
```

On the controller, I have this after the action finishes execution,

```
ViewData["Message"] = displayMessages.ToArray();
Return view("userctrl");
```

"userctrl" is the user control to display messages and the code here looks like this

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>

if (ViewData.ContainsKey("Message")) { %>

    <div class="Message">
        <%= ViewData["Message"] %>

    </div>

<% } %>
```

Now this usercontrol is then returned to the view, as shown above. this works fine if there is a single string but as an array , little more coding is needed in terms of casting it. Please let me know in user control how can I code it ?

Comment: why not return display messages as jSon, its easy to manipulate jSon on client side?

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how I can achieve this ?

Comment: If displayMessages is an array of string you can forgat about jSon and do something like this on your controller  `public string Summary(string Id)
        {
            return String.Join("<br />",displayMessages.ToArray());
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return string from your Action instead of TempData, Something like

```
public string Summary(string Id) { 
            return String.Join("<br />",displayMessages.ToArray());
}
```